# Get the children of the parent category

Tags: categories, loop, navigation, children

I'm trying to get all the children categories to display in this loop but I'm struggling with the code. This is what I have so far.

```
<?php $args=array('orderby' => 'name', 'order' => 'ASC');
    $categories=get_categories($args); 
    foreach ($categories as $cat) { ?>
    <dt><a href="#" class="customer-acquisitiontop" id="<?php echo $cat->slug; ?>" data-filter=".<?php echo $cat->slug; ?>"><h2><?= $cat->cat_name; ?></h2></a></dt>
    <dd><div class="services">
    <?= $categories=get_categories('parent'); ?> /*This should be the children of the parent category */
    </div>
    </dd>
<?php } ?>
```

Any help would be great

Answer (score 28, accepted):

You can't just pass the string "parent" to [`get_categories`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_categories). You have to pass the ID of the parent.

```
$categories=get_categories(
    array( 'parent' => $cat->cat_ID )
);
```

Notice that there are two [similar but not equal "get child" parameters](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_categories) that you can use.

> child_of 
>        (integer) Display all categories that are descendants (i.e. children & grandchildren) of the category identified by its ID. There
>   is no default for this parameter. If the parameter is used, the
>   hide_empty parameter is set to false.
>
> parent 
>       (integer) Display only categories that are direct descendants (i.e. children only) of the category identified by its ID. This does
>   NOT work like the 'child_of' parameter. There is no default for this
>   parameter. [In 2.8.4]

Now you need to loop over the `$categories`. You can't just echo an array.

```
foreach ($categories as $c) {
    var_dump($c);
    // what you really want instead of var_dump is something to
    // to create markup-- list items maybe, For example...
    echo '<li>'.$c->cat_name.'</li>';
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately, that is just giving me an output of Array. No values are being pulled in.

Comment: 'Array' is what happens when you try to echo an array. You need to loop over the array and echo the individual elements.

Comment: You might want to add  'hide_empty' => false. To also show empty categories.

Comment: optionally, you can pull the category ID like this ->`$categories = get_categories( array( 'parent' => get_cat_ID( 'Your Category Name' ) ) );` ... as long as the category name doesn't change

Comment: To get categories which are not post categories, you add `taxonomy` to the array, e.g. `array( 'parent' => 999, 'taxonomy' => 'documentation_category' )`.

Answer (score 7):

Use the code below in your archive.php file.
This code will help you:

```php
$term = get_queried_object();
    
$children = get_terms( $term->taxonomy, array(
    'parent'    => $term->term_id,
    'hide_empty' => false
));
    
if ( $children ) { 
    foreach( $children as $subcat ) {
        echo '<li><a href="' . esc_url(get_term_link($subcat, $subcat->taxonomy)) . '">' . $subcat->name . '</a></li>';
    }
}
```

Comment: Please **[edit] your answer**, and add an explanation: **why** could that solve the problem?

Answer (score 2):

If there are no values in the array you can try the following approach:

```
$last_categories = get_categories(
  array(
    'taxonomy' => 'product_cat',
    'parent' => $sub_category->cat_ID
  )
);
```

Answer (score -1):

To get child categories you can use following code.

```
$category = get_queried_object(); // this is for getting the parent category on archive or any place the category object is called.
$categories=get_categories(
                        array( 'parent' => $category->term_id,
                                'hide_empty' => false )
                                );
```

Notice :- I have used 'hide_empty' => false to show categories with no any posts under it.
Then use the $categories array to loop and make your markup.