# Query Posts Exclude Entire Category

Tags: categories, loop, query-posts, exclude, children

I am using the standard wordpress loop that looks like:

```
    <?php if ( have_posts() ) : while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>
        <h2><?php the_title(); ?></h2>
    <?php endwhile; else: ?>
        <h2>We're sorry...there is no content.</h2>
    <?php endif; ?>
```

Then, what I wanted to do was exclude a certain category from my query, so my code became:

```
    <?php 
        $parent = get_cat_ID("Sports");
        query_posts("cat=-".$parent); 
    ?>
        <?php if ( have_posts() ) : while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>
            <h2><?php the_title(); ?></h2>
        <?php endwhile; else: ?>
            <h2>We're sorry...there is no content.</h2>
        <?php endif; ?>
    <?php wp_reset_query(); ?>
```

Which I thought was right on the money...

So I did some research and discovered this is only excluding the category, not the category and it's subcategories. Is there a way to exclude a specific category and all it's subcategories from the loop?

Thanks,
Josh

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recommend you use the `pre_get_posts` filter or ditch `query_posts` and use `WP Query`.

That way you can easily use `category__not_in (array)` parameter and not mess any other loops up.

```
function exclude_category($query) {

// this requires term id instead of term name so change "20" to the "sport" id
// this assumes "sports" is in a category and not a custom taxonomy
$child_cats = (array) get_term_children('20', 'category');

//only effect main home page query 
if ( $query->is_home() && $query->is_main_query() ) {
$query->set('category__not_in',array_merge(array('20'), $child_cats));
return $query;
}
}

add_filter('pre_get_posts', 'exclude_category');
```

ps. I did not test this but in theory it should work.

Answer (score 0):

This should help you:

[Get the children of the parent category](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/74345/get-the-children-of-the-parent-category?rq=1)

Read all the sub-categories of the parent, loop over the result to get the IDs of them all and then include all IDs in the query_posts() call.

For example (not tested):

```
$parent = get_cat_ID("Sports");
$kids = get_categories( array( 'parent' => $parent ) );
$a = array( $parent );
foreach ( $kids as $kid )
{
  $a[] = $kid->ID;
}

query_posts( "cat=-" . implode( ",", $a ) );
```

Comment: Steve, this gets the child categories no problem...I can even output them as a list, but that's not what I need. What I am looking for is something that will do that automatically, so later on if I add more child categories to the category I won't have to go back and manually exclude them from the loop.

Comment: Hi Josh, there should be no manual additions at all, I've updated my answer with a (untested) code example.

Comment: I tried your code and it seemed like nothing happened, not sure why it didn't work...any ideas?