# How to display get_the_category of post showing only CHILD of category "X"

Tags: categories

I'm trying to display the get_category_category limiting the results to only the child categories of parent "666".

So a post may have a number of categories e.g. "1234", "666", "666/1341", "5", "5/17" but I only want to show the child of "666".

```
$args = array( 'numberposts' => '5','post_status' => 'publish','category' => '1234','category__not_in' => '680', 'orderby' => 'post_date', 'order' => 'DESC' );
$recent_posts = wp_get_recent_posts($args);
{

///I want to return the category for each post in this loop that is within the "666" category.
///E.g get_the_category($recent['ID']) where the category is a child of 666

echo "POST ID" . $recent['ID'] . " CHILD CATEGORY ". $childcategory; 
}
```

The above loop will return the last 5 posts in category "1234" with each child category of "666".

e.g.

- POST ID 10 CHILD CATEGORY 1341
- POST ID 11 CHILD CATEGORY 1341
- POST ID 14 CHILD CATEGORY 99
- POST ID 19 CHILD CATEGORY 1341
- POST ID 23 CHILD CATEGORY 99

Answer (score 1):

You can do this by getting the child categories of that category first, then passing them as an array to your query.

```
$categories=get_categories(
    array( 'parent' => $cat->cat_ID )
);

$cat_list = [];
foreach ($categories as $c) {
    $cat_list[] = $c->term_id;
}
```

ref: [Get the children of the parent category](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/74345/get-the-children-of-the-parent-category)

This won't/might not work, but it's usually worth trying passing an array where you could pass an integer in WordPress:

```
$args = array( 'numberposts' => '5','post_status' => 'publish','category' => $cat_list,'category__not_in' => '680', 'orderby' => 'post_date', 'order' => 'DESC' );
```

`wp_get_recent_posts` uses `get_posts` & `get_post` accepts an ID of a category, at the time of writing it doesn't mention an array... So you might need to use `WP_Query`:

```
$query = new WP_Query( array( 'category__and' => $cat_list ) );
```

see: https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query

Answer (score 0):

You can use `array_map` so you can return only the categories that you want. For example:

```
array_map( function( $cat ) {
        if ( $cat->parent != 0 ) {
            return $cat;
        }
     },
     get_the_category()
);
```